# Generating multivariate Gaussian distribution in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I used this link here for some Rcpp code to generate samples from a multivariate Gaussian distribution: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/

Rcpp code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat mvrnormArma(int n, arma::vec mu, arma::mat sigma) {
   int ncols = sigma.n_cols;
   arma::mat Y = arma::randn(n, ncols);
   return arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(sigma);
}
```

R code:

```
mvrnormArma(n = 10000, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1), 2, 2))
```

This worked fine until recently and I get the following error:

```
error: Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout
```

Does anyone else have this problem?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: could this be due to `sigma` and `Sigma`

Comment: @user20650 Yup. It's working at my end if I use `sigma`

Comment: @ekstroem ; although using `[S]igma` produces a different error than the op receives.

Comment: @user-2147482565 using armadillo's built-in [mvnrnd()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#mvnrnd) function is likely to be faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me with the version uploaded to CRAN today.  Which version do you claim an error with?

```
R> library(RcppArmadillo)
R> packageVersion("RcppArmadillo")
[1] ‘0.9.700.2.0’
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/57760655/question.cpp")

R> #mvrnormArma(n = 10000, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1), 2, 2))
R> set.seed(123)  # make it reproducible
R> mvrnormArma(n = 10, mu = c(0, 0), sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1), 2, 2))
            [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] -0.6853851  1.811730
 [2,]  0.9302219  0.741069
 [3,] -0.2260918 -0.119390
 [4,]  0.9513753  0.315338
 [5,]  0.0699539  0.670879
 [6,]  0.9767215  0.332053
 [7,]  2.1650415  0.966927
 [8,] -1.8262054  1.294966
 [9,]  0.5804146  1.062635
[10,] -0.0592898  2.270198
R>
```

I used your C++ code as is, and just adjusted Sigma to lowercase sigma.

Comment: my apologies, it works now. I'm still not sure why it did this before as I just ran the code again, but I just tried this again and no errors